# How extract human name information from wikidata API?

Tags: wikidata-api

i have a problem understanding how wikidata.org is working ! even the documentation is not clear as facebook API , well my target is to downliad

ALL available human names (full name , first name (in all languages )) + human language + Gender + country.

Please do not -1 , i am learning and honestly i tried a lot but it is very  obscure how wikidata query is working.

and how can i download all database without timeout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this script but sometimes it works , and 90% r time return timeout ? why

```
SELECT ?given_name ?nameLabel ?given_nameLabel ?sex_or_genderLabel ?native_languageLabel   WHERE {
  OPTIONAL { ?given_name wdt:P31 wd:Q5. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],ar". }
  OPTIONAL { ?given_name wdt:P21 ?sex_or_gender. }
  OPTIONAL { ?given_name wdt:P735 ?name. }
  OPTIONAL { ?given_name wdt:P103 ?native_language. }

}
LIMIT 100
```